# fillter an array image links with jpg, jpeg, png, webp in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Can someone help me, please

I have an array of images URLs and using the filter() method to get only the links with supported images using regex or endsWith(). I have been trying all morning

Thank you so much

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: If you have already tried something, please share it with us, so we can help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a regex where the last part of this string is any of the file extensions. We can validate using the [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

Regex explanation:

- `\.` Matches a dot literally
- `(jpe?g|png|webp)` any of these file extensions. (`e?` means the e is optional, this way we match jpg and jpeg)
- `$` end of the string. Without this we could also match something like `image.jpg.gif`

```js
const urls = [
  "image.jpg",
  "image.jpeg",
  "image.png",
  "image.webp",
  "image.svg",
  "image.gif",
];

const result = urls.filter((url) => /\.(jpe?g|png|webp)$/.test(url));

console.log(result);
```